# Error Using ToolTips with Jinja2

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I'm having a problem with Jinja2 when I try to use tooltips with a text input filed: "invalid syntax for function call expression".

This is my code:

```
{{ Wformulario.WCPO_Nro_Part(class="form-control input-sm inteiro tooltips", data-container="body", data-placement="bottom", data-original-title="Informe o Numero de Participantes: 0 a 99", tabindex="3") }}
```

This works perfectly (I just remove data-container, data-placement,...):

```
{{ Wformulario.WCPO_Nro_Part(class="form-control input-sm inteiro tooltips", tabindex="3") }}
```

This works perfectly either:

```
<input class="form-control input-sm inteiro tooltips" data-container="body" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="Informe o Numero de Participantes: 0 a 99"> </input>
```

I don´t know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When calling a function with keyword arguments, you can only use valid identifiers for keywords; these identifiers can *not* use `-` as that is the subtraction operator. `data-container` is not a valid identifier.

I am assuming that you are using WTForms here to produce your inputs. In that case you can replace `data-` with `data_` and WTForms will render these attributes correctly using a dash instead of the underscore:

```
{{ Wformulario.WCPO_Nro_Part(class="form-control input-sm inteiro tooltips", 
                             data_container="body", data_placement="bottom", 
                             data_original_title="Informe o Numero de Participantes: 0 a 99",
                             tabindex="3") }}
```

Note that only the *first* `_` is replaced, so this creates:

```
<input class="form-control input-sm inteiro tooltips"
       data-container="body" data-placement="bottom" 
       data-original_title="Informe o Numero de Participantes: 0 a 99"> </input>
```

Note the `_` in `original_title`.

To work around that you'd have to pass in the information in a dictionary instead, and use `**` (double-splat) call instead:

```
{{ Wformulario.WCPO_Nro_Part(class="form-control input-sm inteiro tooltips", 
                             data_container="body", data_placement="bottom", 
                             tabindex="3",
                             **{'data-original-title': "Informe o Numero de Participantes: 0 a 99"}) }}
```

Now the `data-original-title` argument is being passed in not as a keyword argument but as part of a dictionary.

Comment: When I use:    {{ Wformulario.WCPO_Nro_Part(class="form-control input-sm inteiro tooltips", data_container="body", data_placement="bottom", tabindex="3", **{'data-original-title': "Informe o Numero de Participantes: 0 a 99"}) }}  it worked but WTF didn't replace - with _ so the tooltip appear on top. Then I tried:    {{ Wformulario.WCPO_Nro_Part(class="form-control input-sm inteiro tooltips", tabindex="3", **{'data-original-title': "Informe o Numero de Participantes: 0 a 99", 'data-placement': "bottom", 'data-container': "body"}) }} and it worked perfectly.